# Is it possible to use Polymer and Brick together?

Tags: html, polymer, mozilla-brick

There are some great components provided by [Brick](http://mozilla.github.io/brick/) and other provided by [Polymer](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/polymer-ui-elements.html). Is it technically possible to use them together ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

x-tags (the basis for Brick) and Polymer use exactly the same polyfills, but x-tags uses a reduced set.

Brick itself ships as a single minified JS file, so that distribution doesn't work with Polymer (if you load `brick.min.js` and `platform.js`, there are polyfill collisions).

However, the x-tags themselves can work with Polymer. If you load `platform.js` (the polyfills), then `x-tag-core` (x-tag's sugaring layer), then you can import Polymer elements and load x-tags together with no problems.

This process can be simplified using imports, but x-tags/brick doesn't ship with supporting imports files (yet, but we are trying to work that out). There's an article at http://www.polymer-project.org/articles/polymer-xtag-vanilla.html with more information and some examples.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It is 100% possible to use Brick & Polymer, see this code - 
http://www.polymer-project.org/articles/polymer-xtag-vanilla.html
and Code - https://github.com/x-tag/interop-examples

Without import, here is the flow

- load https://github.com/Polymer/platform/blob/master/platform.js
- load https://github.com/x-tag/core/blob/master/src/core.js
- load custom element - https://github.com/mozilla/brick/blob/master/dist/x-tag-flipbox.js

Here you go,
See jsfiddle for this !
http://jsfiddle.net/nsisodiya/266tt/

```
<head>
<script src="http://rawgit.com/Polymer/platform/0.2.4/platform.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="http://rawgit.com/mozilla/brick/1.0.1/dist/x-tag-flipbox.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://rawgit.com/x-tag/core/1.0.0-beta-4/src/core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://rawgit.com/mozilla/brick/1.0.1/dist/x-tag-flipbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely! That's the beauty of web components: the internal implementation of a component has no meaning outside of that component. To the rest of the world, it's just another DOM element that has attributes and properties and fires events.

**Update**: This will be the case *when the Web Components specs are implemented natively in browsers*. Until then, both Brick and Polymer share the same underlying polyfills for these features, however, I can't seem to get them to work together (see [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Tm3y9ODvPRK2o1TDGPMI)). This probably means they're using slightly different versions of the polyfills.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not any more.

Brick is forsaken since 2014, according to [MDN itself](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Apps/Tools_and_frameworks/Web_components).